# Spring boot: get initial h2 sql based on environment

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, h2

I am using h2 database and trying to get sql based on the environment
I tried to set spring.datasources.data with different value but none of them work.
For example if I set it as  local or local/data-h2.sql
ResourceNotFoundException: ServletContext resource defined by 'spring.datasource.data' does not exist

```
project structure:
    main
      --java
      --resources
        --local
          --data-h2.sql
        --pro
          --data-h2.sql

application.yml
spring:
    profiles: local
    jpa:
        show-sql: false
        hibernate:
            ddl-auto: create-drop
    h2:
        console:
            enabled: true
    datasource:
        url: jdbc:h2:./build/db/h2;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
        username: anyUser
        password: anyPw
        platform: h2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specific the location of the sql file.
You can use

```
spring.datasources.data=classpath*:local/data.sql
```